# C++: member function address (function pointers)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a **class X** which has this method:

```
void setRxHandler(void (*h)(int));
```

And I want to pass to it a member function that exists in instances of **class Y**.

```
void comm_rxHandler(int status);
```

I tried the following:

```
x.setRxHandler(comm_rxHandler)
```

But it get the following compile error (I'm using Qt):

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘X::setRxHandler(< unresolved overloaded function type>)’

So, how can I do that?

I noticed if I declare comm_rxHandler (class Y) as static, I have no errors. But I want comm_rxHandler as a non-static method. Also I want setRxHandler method (class X) to be generic and not class-specific. So I can't declare that method as:

```
setRxHandler(void (Y::*h)(int))
```

How to do that? Can you help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: In C++0x, you should consider making the argument `std::function<void(int)>`, which works for all sorts of callable objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is now, the `setRxHandler` prototype takes a pointer to a function that doesn't return anything and takes an `int`. As you have noticed, this won't work with member functions because they can't be called like a normal function (you have to handle the `this` pointer as well, which means having an instance of that class to call the method on).

To make it both work with member functions and non-specific (*generic*), you have to either make a base class and have all classes you want to use `setRxHandler` with derive from that class:

```
class Base { ... };
class Derived : public Base { ... };

// then for the prototype
void setRxHandler(void (Base::*h)(int)) { ... }
// and you can use setRxHandler for all types that derive from Base, which gives you more control than the second option, which is:
```

or use templates:

```
template<typename T>
void setRxHandler(void (T::*h)(int)) { ... }
```

With the template option, you really have no control over what class will be used with `setRxHandler` (excluding RTTI), which can be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't support [bound methods](http://bitstructures.com/2007/11/python-bound-methods).  To invoke a member function through a function pointer, you need to have two things: an instance of the class and the function pointer.

So `setRxHandler(void (Y::*h)(int))` is almost correct.  You need to declare it as:

```
void setRxHandler(Y*, void (Y::*h)(int));
```

To invoke `setRxHandler()`, you need to pass it arguments as follows:

```
Y y;
setRxHandler(&y, &Y::comm_rxHandler);
```

In the `setRxHandler()` method, you can invoke the function pointer using this syntax:

```
void setRxHandler ( Y* y, void (Y::*h)(int) )
{
    // ...
    (y->*h)(0);
    // ...
}
```

To make generic, you need to abstract the `Y` parameter away, but this is difficult to get right.  Check out [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function.html) for an existing implementation that supports this use case, and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Change your callback to this:

```
void setRxHandler(std::function(<void(int)>);
```

Then you can use binders:

```
setRxHandler( std::bind(&class_name::comm_rxHandler, obj) );
```

(`std::function` and `std::bind` are part of the upcomming next version of the C++ standard. It's quite likely your compiler already comes with them. If not, they might live in namespace `std::tr1`. If all else fails, you will find them at [boost](http://www.boost.org) - which is where they were invented - as `boost::function` and `boost::bind`.)

You can, however, also pass non-member or static functions to `setRxHandler`, as well as function objects (which is the result of `std::bind`).

If your compiler already supports lambda functions (also part of the next standard, but already supported by, e.g., recent versions of GCC and VC), you can also use one of those:

```
setRxHandler( [](){obj.comm_rxHandler();} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a base class for `Y` and use that (to avoid being "class specific"), or use templates:

```
template <class T>
setRxHandler(void (T::*h)(int));
```

But then this may raise questions of how to use the member function (you tell us if it does).

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, C++ does not provide this functionality.

Another option you could use is [libsigc++](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/) which is widely used in gtkmm, see [this example](http://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++-tutorial/stable/ch02s02.html) in their tutorial for instance on how to pass pointers to member-functions. Your example could look something like:

```
// sigc::slot<void, int> is a 'slot' to hold a function with return type void 
// and 1 int argument.
void setRxHandler(sigc::slot<void, int> slot);
void comm_rxHandler(int status);

//sigc::mem_fun() can convert a member function to a function slot.
x.setRxHandler(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &X::comm_rxHandler));
```